# How to transit from Choice State Step Function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, serverless-framework-step-functions

The input that is being sent from previous state is in this form:

```
  [
{
"bucketName": "test-heimdall-employee-data",
"executionId": "ca9f1e5e-4d3a-4237-8a10-8860bb9d58be_1586771571368",
"feedType": "lenel_badge",
"chunkFileKeys": "chunkFileLocation/lenel_badge/68ac7180-69a0-401a-b30c-8f809acf3a1c_1586771581154.csv",
"sanityPassFileKeys": "chunkFileLocation/lenel_badge/0098b86b-fe3c-45ca-a067-4d4a826ee2c1_1586771588882.json"
},
  {
"bucketName": "test-heimdall-employee-data",
"executionId": "ca9f1e5e-4d3a-4237-8a10-8860bb9d58be_1586771571368",
"feedType": "lenel_badge",
"errorFilePath": "error/lenel_badge/2a899128-339d-4262-bb2f-a70cc60e5d4e/1586771589234_2e06e043-ad63-4217-9b53-66405ac9a0fc_1586771581493.csv",
"chunkFileKeys": "chunkFileLocation/lenel_badge/2e06e043-ad63-4217-9b53-66405ac9a0fc_1586771581493.csv",
"sanityPassFileKeys": "chunkFileLocation/lenel_badge/f6957aa7-6e22-496a-a6b8-4964da92cb73_1586771588793.json"
  },
 {
"bucketName": "test-heimdall-employee-data",
"executionId": "ca9f1e5e-4d3a-4237-8a10-8860bb9d58be_1586771571368",
"feedType": "lenel_badge",
"errorFilePath": "error/lenel_badge/8050eb12-c5e6-4ae9-8c4b-0ac539f5c189/1586771589293_1bb32e6c-03fc-4679-9c2f-5a4bca46c8aa_1586771581569.csv",
"chunkFileKeys": "chunkFileLocation/lenel_badge/1bb32e6c-03fc-4679-9c2f-5a4bca46c8aa_1586771581569.csv",
"sanityPassFileKeys": "chunkFileLocation/lenel_badge/48960b7c-04e0-4cce-a77a-44d8834289df_1586771588870.json"
  }
  ]
```

state machine workflow design: [image]

How do I extract "feedType"value from the above inputs and transit to next state and also pass entire inputs to next state?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access the input JSON you started your statemachine with using: `$$.Execution.Input.todo`. Other than that you can't directly access previous state from one step to the next.

As an example lets say you have `A->B->C`
Lets say you went through `A` which gave a new field: `a : 1`, and then you went through `B` and it returns `b : 2`, when you get to `C` you will only have `b : 2`. But if `B` also return `a : 1` you would then have `{a : 1, b : 2}` at `C`. Which is typically what you do to pass state from a step a couple of steps prior.

There are other things which people do, such as storing data in an `s3` bucket and accessing that bucket in different stages. You can also query a step function as well but that can be messy.

Other hacks include adding a pass step in a parallel block, but these hacks are not good, the correct way is to pass the data on between your steps, or hopefully have what you need in your execution input.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your previous state input it looks like `feed_type` is a constant. Assuming key  to your entire input is "input" so that it's dictionary like `{"input":[{...},{...}]}` and so on. So to access the value of `feed_type` you can simply do `$.input[0].feed_type`.

Choice state by default passes the entire input passed to it into the next stage. So to whatever next stage it goes to, that stage is going to have same input that was passed to choice state.

To understand it better or as a proof of concept check the below Step Function in which **Hello** state is a `choice` state and other 2 states are simple pass states.

[image: Sample Step Function]

And if you will see below the *input* and *output* of Choice state. It's the **same**.

[image]

Hope it helps.